# SSIS: How do I create tables using Foreach Loop Container?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, adventureworks, foreach-loop-container

I got a bunch of .csv files each containing a script that would create a certain table.

I want to create tables using these scripts in said files (each table to be created using one file).

I got a `foreach` loop container that specifies the path and which files to use.

I don't know how to configure the `Execute SQL Task` to execute the script in each one of these files in order to create a table.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a great idea, to be honest. If you're looping around files in a folder, then someone could easily edit one of those scripts to be malicious.

Comment: It's just for learning purposes.

Comment: @FayçalSalhi I agree with Larnu: it is really really risky to loop through a directory and blindly execute every file in it. Furthermore: if the files contain DDL, why are they delivered in csv format and not sql or something? Anyways, if you still want to procede you might try the following: Define a String variable in SSIS. Then - within your loop - call a script task, which reads the content of your file into this variable. Then configure your SQL task to use command from variable and assign the string variable.

Comment: Not sure how to do all that. Still just a beginner

Comment: Beginner in what? SSIS, SQL, programming? Start small: start with a C# Console Application and try to process one file. There are good tutorials online. If you have this (opeining file, reading content, storing to variable) it's easy to port this to SSIS.

Comment: I meant beginner at SSIS. I really need to know how to do this thing because it's for an assignment

Comment: They should be .sql files and not .csv if they contain SQL script. Use a custom Script task that reads the file contents into a variable, then map the variable as SQL command in your Execute SQL Task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Execute SQL Task with an input parameter of the table name (I would use the table name that the 'for each' container provides. I would first drop the table if it exists and then recreate it with a create table command (in the Execute SQL Task).

As other people have noted you may want to be careful with tasks that drop tables but I have created plenty of SSIS packages that involve truncating and/or creating tables.